# ERROR:pop index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.6

This is my code:

```
word = str(input())
list = []

for i in range(len(word)):
    B = word[i]
    list.append(B)

D = list.pop(0)
E = D.upper()
list.insert(0, E)



capitalized_word = ""
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    C = list.pop(i)
    capitalized_word = capitalized_word + C


print(capitalized_word)
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
wORd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akarsh/Desktop/python/capitalization.py", line 16, in <module>
    C = list.pop(i)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Here i is taking values from 0 to 3 which is in the range of index of the list but still i am getting this error

Comment: The list becomes shorter with each iteration, but the indexes are up to its original length.

Answer (score 0):

You're popping the **former** values from 0 to 3 from the list. Once those values are popped, the list is smaller.

Comment: Can you please suggest another method to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is because [list.pop](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.list.pop) modifies original list, and range(len(word)) is calculated only once in the beginning of the loop.

So you asked for a better way to do it. Use [str.join()](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.str.join) function to concat strings in a list. Like this:

```
capitalized_word = "".join(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, *don't* call your variable `list`. It is a Python built-in type and using the name for something else it will cause you baffling problems.

To start with, this

```
word = str(input())
list = []

for i in range(len(word)):
    B = word[i]
    list.append(B)
```

is a very cumbersome way to turn a string into a list. Do it this way instead:

```
>>> word = "fred"
>>> mylist = list(word)
>>> mylist
['f', 'r', 'e', 'd']
```

To capitalize each word in the list, don't use `pop()` because it changes the length of the list, and your expression `range(0, len(list))` assumes the length won't change. There is no need to extract your letter from the list in order to build up `capitalized_word`:

```
>>> capitalized_word = ""
>>> for c in mylist:
    capitalized_word += c
>>> capitalized_word
'fred'
```

You will note that this is in fact not capitalized because your code doesn't actually upshift it. To achieve that,

```
>>> capitalized_word = ""
>>> for c in mylist:
    capitalized_word += c.upper()
>>> capitalized_word
'FRED'
```

This shows you why your method isn't working, but it is not the best approach to working with strings in Python. Don't actually do it this way. Use built-in facilities instead:

```
>>> word = "fred"
>>> capitalized_word = word.upper()
>>> capitalized_word
'FRED'
```

Similiarly, don't do this to provide an initial capital:

```
D = list.pop(0)
E = D.upper()
list.insert(0, E)
```

Instead do this:

```
>>> word = "fred"
>>> capitalized_word = word.title()
>>> capitalized_word
'Fred'
```